# push object into an array failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push object into an new array.

```
var final = [],
  temp_obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

  var splitted = obj[i].split(":")[0]
  if (obj[i] != null && obj[i] != '') {
    temp_obj["name"] = splitted;
  }

  final.push(temp_obj);

}

console.log(final)
```

The result I got is I'm getting same result for my object, which part I did wrong?

Comment: What does the code inside of `obj` look like? Please also include that.

Comment: You need to include example input and the intended output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign empty `temp_obj` inside for loop like following code :

```
var final = [],temp_obj;  

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  temp_obj = {};
  var splitted = obj[i].split(":")[0]
  if (obj[i] != null && obj[i] != '') {
     temp_obj["name"] = splitted;
  }

  final.push(temp_obj);
}

console.log(final)
```

Comment: where does this obj come from ? The one with obj.lenght

Comment: @FurkanOrhan Another references of course. Assumed for loop already in action. OP problem is `The result I got is I'm getting same result for my object`, we know that for loop already iterated.

Comment: @FurkanOrhan that's something you should ask OP

Comment: I think there is no point declaring `temp_obj` outside of the loop!

Comment: @RayonDabre that's my mistake.

Comment: @JenniferAniston yeah..I would suggest you to accept the correct answer as it will help others who will search for similar questions!

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your null and empty checking condition to one step to the top. Like below, other vice you will get null point issues.

```
  var final = [],
  temp_obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
   temp_obj = {};

  if (obj[i] != null && obj[i] != '') {
    var splitted = obj[i].split(":")[0]
    temp_obj["name"] = splitted;
  }

  final.push(temp_obj);

}

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `final.push()` should be inside the loop ([demo](http://jsbin.com/jajaqopeja/edit?js,console))

```
var obj = [ 'a:b', 'c:d', 'e:f' ], // just guessing
  final = [],
  temp_obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

  var splitted = obj[i].split(":")[0];
  if (obj[i] !== null && obj[i] !== '') {
    temp_obj.name = splitted;
    final.push( temp_obj );
  }

}

console.log(final);
```